# Use logical OR || to combine two integers?

Tags: c++, logical-operators, ofstream, bitwise-or

In [this MSDN article on file sharing mode with std::ofstream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa277521%28v=vs.60%29.aspx), Microsoft writes:

> To combine the `filebuf::sh_read` and `filebuf::sh_write` modes, use the logical OR (`||`) operator.

Both constants are of type `int`, as far as I can see, so I don't understand why we should use the *logical* OR instead of the bitwise OR (`|`). I always thought that the logical OR produces a Boolean value, so there is no way of interpreting the result?

Comment: It's not unheard of to see bugs in their documentation...

Comment: Unless someone thought of a convoluted design where "1"(casted from true) was the combined mode.

Comment: That's a fairly extensive typo...

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was going to say. It may be mistake (and I think it is), but not "typo", the operator name is also different - it's not like "logical OR (`|`)" or "bitwise OR( `||` )". Interesting

Comment: Ok, guys: shall I post this as an answer: "I suspect that it's a thinko"?

Comment: Feh, it's a VS6 doc page.  C++98 wasn't even ratified yet.  It didn't have the `<iostream>` header nor the std namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a documentation error. In later versions, they have restructured the documentation, delegating the explanation of *bitmask types* to [the following page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/888a6zcz%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> A bitmask type can be implemented as either an integer type or an enumeration. In either case, you can perform bitwise operations (such as AND and OR) on values of the same bitmask type. The elements A and B of a bitmask type are nonzero values such that A & B is zero.

Get there via

1. google
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5785s5ts(v=vs.71).aspx
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7z434859(v=vs.71).aspx
4. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t60aakye(v=VS.71).aspx
5. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1et11xw(v=VS.71).aspx
6. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kb732k7(v=VS.71).aspx

Yay! for MSDN navigation. Also, VS2010 documentation has been altered *again*: [the newest page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y1et11xw.aspx) doesn't even describe the semantics of the flags fields anymore (allthough, you could take one *mention* of `_Mode | ios_base::out` to imply  that the params are bitmask combinations)